# asp.net (vb) pages with a dos style output display

Tags: asp.net, console, vb.net-2010

I currently have a vb.net console app that performs some file maintenance actions such as copying directories and files for backup purposes.

I have been asked create a web based version of the app that can be accessed, and use an output style window similar to what my audience is used to from the console app.

Essentially like a terminal/console style window embedded in an asp.net page, to display output progress on file copy activities.

I can write the copy and other file related commands.

Is this possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to?  To be clear, what you would end up with was an asp page that is *styled* to look like a console app.  We moved away from console apps for a reason.  Think about what would really make your user more efficient.

Comment: Yes, it is entirely possible and entirely reasonable to think that some users might favour the command-line. I say go for it!

Comment: Don't worry, Console apps are still very popular and widely used.

Comment: @Biscuits I agree, they are very widely used.  They are very widely used because programmers are lazy and dont fully consider whats best for the user instead considering only whats best for the programmer.

Comment: Additionally, this question is written very broadly.  You ask if this is possible, we say yes.  It is hard to go much further than that without more information from you.  Please post code you've attempted and errors you're receiving.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realize this was a broad question, I haven't put together any code specifically for this task yet, I have first been trying to get a feel as to whether it was plausible. I will make my first stab at it this week and post the code if I run into any difficulties.